# Are dynamically allocated nodes of lists accessible throughout program?

Tags: c, data-structures

I have created a linked list in C. I dynamically allocate memory as

'''

```
struct node* createNode(value) {
    struct node* newNode = 
    malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  newNode->data = value;
  newNode->left = NULL;
  newNode->right = NULL;

  return newNode;
}

struct node* insertLeft(struct node* root, int value) {
  root->left = createNode(value);
  return root->left;
}

int main() {
  struct node* root = createNode(1);
insertLeft(root,12);
  //Create more nodes
  postorder(root);
}

void postorder(struct node* root) {
    if (root == NULL) return;
    postorder(root->left);
    postorder(root->right);
    printf("%d ->", root->data);
}
```

'''

Now the root node I am getting after insertion is of the newly inserted element.Because I return this new node. How come while traversing the top-most root is passed to postorder.

Also if I don't return this new node it should still exist in the memory so why return?

Comment: If you don't `return` the node address it will be forgotten. The memory you allocate will still exist, but be inaccessible because you don't know where it is. It will also cause a memory leak becuase you can't `free` it. You need to `return` it so that `root->left = createNode(value);` has a node address to assign.

Answer (score 1):

> Now the root node I am getting after insertion is of the newly inserted element.Because I return this new node.

That's not the case. When you call `insertLeft()`, you don't assign its return value to anything. So root still points to the node with data == 1.

Comment: Then to whom is it returning the node. If you could elaborate on your answer.